# In Flume-NG, is there a way to check the heartbeat on the http agent

Tags: flume

I want to put an ELB in front of the Flume-NG agents, I was wondering if there is a way to check the status/heartbeat of the flume agent without really sending any event into the agent.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to put an ELB in front of the agents? If you have multiple agents then use one of the sink processors to get your events through. You could use [Failover](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#failover-sink-processor) or [Load-Balancing](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#load-balancing-sink-processor).

I'm not aware of any way to query the status of a Flume agent.

Comment: Thats how we have been testing right now. However, with ELB we have some AWS cloudwatch alerts on it, which helps to monitor the traffic and other things for non-flume version.